# Apache AddType to all extention?

Tags: apache-2.2

-edit- it looks like i didnt need to do anything with apache. I have a dummy test and it seems to work with every url and extension i gave it.

I am follwing these awesome instructions http://blog.ruski.co.za/page/Install-Mono-on-Ubuntu.aspx

and at this point i understand what is happening (except i dont reconize why .config would need to be an ext)

I would like all urls to use x-asp-net so urls like `site.com/data/user/more/title anything goes.lol woot.falseExt with space`

```
AddType application/x-asp-net .aspx .ashx .asmx .ascx .asax .config .ascx
```

How do i do that? also it would be nice if i can make it so php still runs normally on other sites but thats not my concern right now. I need all urls to be able to run on this server/site

Answer (score 0):

Use mod_rewrite to rewrite "strange" URLs to URLs being served by an application.